# Simulating Effects of Sampling after Butterworth Filter

Tags: filters, sampling, analog

Is there anyway to simulate the effects of sampling an analog signal with Python/MATLAB? I am trying to show what happens to the frequency domain (magnitude and phase) of the analog signal after it has been passed through an analog Butterworth filter and that subsequent signal is sampled.

How would I simulate sampling the frequency spectrum shown below?

````
W = np.arange(-1*(10E3)*2*np.pi, (10E3)*2*np.pi, 1)
b = [3.93785014e+24]
a = [1.00000000e+00, 4.85527277e+04, 1.17868368e+09, 1.81406467e+13, 
1.86130267e+17, 1.21074613e+21, 3.93785014e+24]

fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Butterworth [n=6, f_3dB=2kHz]')

plt.plot(w / (2*np.pi), 20 * np.log10(abs(h)))
plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude [dB]')
plt.grid(which='both', axis='both')
```
````

Comment: What are the effects that you want to simulate?